# How does open drain io act as bidirectional

Tags: io, open-drain

Could someone explain how open drain io acts as bidirectional. Whether it is actually bidirectional or it can act only as input or output at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Line is read through a high impedance input. The line is controlled by the internal n-channel mosfet and the pull-up resistor. By turning off the mosfet, it releases the line so it is a passive input. When it turns on the fet, it tries to force the line low, but it still reads the input to check if the line is logic low or not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVsEfu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: When the FET is on how can BUF1 "still reads the input to check if the line is logic low or not" ? The line HAS to be low because it's being driver that way by the FET right? how else could the pin be high? If something else is driving the line high while the FET is pulling it low then surely some magic smoke will occur (a short?)

Comment: @scuba it's a non-ideal setup and has some resistance and other circuitry that could affect it. The fet could be damaged and so you set the pin low, but still reads high. If we look at the actual pin circuit diagram at any given microcontroller you can see it's much more complex than this one paragraph representation describes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the device in question.  If you are speaking of a microcontroller or a chip that uses something I2C communications, the chip itself can both monitor the line to see what the current logic level is *as well as* drive that line LO so as to signal other devices.

However, there are open-drain buffers where the buffer can drive the line LO but can not itself monitor the line to read its' current logic level.

Let's take the example of a microcontroller.  You can set the pin as an output and driven LO to signal other devices on the bus or you can set the pin as an input and read the current level on the bus.  Both of these actions are possible on a single pin, as opposed to requiring separate pins for input and output.

Answer (score 1):

If, beside the open drain, your pin also can be read, then you can use it as input by not enabling the output FET.

This is commonly done for multi-point communication like i2C and Dallas/Maxim 1-wire.